# How to export Application Map in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, dependency-management, azure-monitoring

I would like to export structured data from an Application Insights Application Map.
E.g. as a CSV file.

I would like to use this data for quality assurance related tasks, to identify integrated systems and dependencies of the application. With less manual work.

Here is an example for an application map visualisation:
[image]

For this I would like to generate an export file, which I can use for further manual and automated processing.
I didn't find such functionality in Azure. Is there such? Are there alternative tools which can provide such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the box functionality to export the Application Map. However, the map is built using the available data in the different telemetry tables. That means you can write a Kusto query to get all the data used to built the map, for example by using this Kusto query:

```
search in (dependencies, requests, availabilityResults) *
```

Then you get all the results and you can use the `$table` column to analyze the data based on the telemetry type. You can then export the result to a .csv file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage Export capability, and export the data to Azure storage account etc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry (This feature is deprecated in favor of another alternative, but can achieve same end goal.)

Another alternative would be depending on the language, you can write custom Channel to export telemetry to json/something else.